# Implementation Bash pipes and redirections in c

Tags: c, bash, fork, wait, waitpid

[interesting screen lldb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49QU7.png)

I encounter an issue with my implementation of pipes and output redirection.
It works fine individually, but when I try
`'ls | wc > a',`
it doesn't function as in real Bash. It creates the file 'a', but it doesn't redirect the output of `'ls | wc'` to this file and creat infinite loop It waits for the pid, but I have the loop to wait for all the function at the end, I made a mistake, but I don't know where ?

I have a function for creating my pipes and their execution and the same for redirection I can't find the solution i my probleme
why my 'ls | wc > file' is not redirected from my file

**pipeline.c**

```
void create_pipe(int pipe_fd[2], int i, int last) 
{
    if (i < (last - 1))
    {
        if (pipe(pipe_fd) == -1) 
        {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void close_pipes_in_parent(int i, t_data *data, int *input_fd) 
{
    if (i != data->first)
        close(*input_fd);
    if (i < data->last) 
    {
        close(data->pipe_fd[1]);
        *input_fd = data->pipe_fd[0];
    }

}


pid_t fork_process_pipe(int i, int input_fd, t_data *data, t_Token *curr, char **envp, t_Token *lst_tok) 
{
    pid_t pid = fork(); 

    if (pid == 0)
    { 
        printf("111111111111111111");
        if (i != data->first) 
        {
                dup2(input_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(input_fd);
        }
        if (i < data->last) 
        {
                dup2(data->pipe_fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(data->pipe_fd[0]);
                close(data->pipe_fd[1]);
        }
        data->path_exe = ft_get_reading(data, curr, envp);
        if(!data->path_exe)
        {
            printf("Bash : command not found : %s\n", data->cmd[0]);
            ft_free_tabtab(data->cmd);
            free_token(lst_tok);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (execve(data->path_exe, data->cmd, envp) == -1) 
        {
            ft_free_tabtab(data->cmd);
            free(data->path_exe);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        free(curr->Token_str);
        free(curr);
    }
    return (pid);
}
```

**redir.c**

```
int *creat_fd_out(t_data *data, t_Token *curr, int *output_fd)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(i < data->nb_file)
    {
        output_fd[i] =  open(curr->next->next->Token_str, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0644);
        if (output_fd[i] == -1) 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        i++;
        curr = curr->next->next ;
    }
    return(output_fd);
}

void close_fd_in(t_data *data, int *output_fd)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(i < data->nb_file)
    {    
        close(output_fd[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

pid_t fork_process_redi(t_data *data, t_Token *curr, char **envp, t_Token *lst_tok) 
{
    pid_t pid = fork(); 
    int *output_fd = malloc(data->nb_file * sizeof(int)); 
    
    if (pid == 0)
    { 
        if ((curr->type == E_WORD && curr->next != NULL) && (curr->next->Token_str[0] == '>'))
        {  
            data->path_exe = ft_get_reading(data, curr, envp);
            if(!data->path_exe)
            {
                printf("Bash : command not found : %s\n", data->cmd[0]);
                ft_free_tabtab(data->cmd);
                free_token(lst_tok);
            }
            output_fd = creat_fd_out(data, curr, output_fd);
            dup2(output_fd[data->nb_file -1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close_fd_in(data, output_fd);

        }
        if (execve(data->path_exe, data->cmd, envp) == -1) 
        {
            ft_free_tabtab(data->cmd);
            free(data->path_exe);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        free(curr->Token_str);
        free(curr);
    }
    return (pid);
}
```

`lanch_exe.c`

```
void execute_pipeline_redirection(t_data *data, t_Token *list_token, char **envp) 
{
    int index_fork;
    int input_fd;
    t_Token *curr;

    data->last = data->nb_cmd;
    curr = list_token;
    input_fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    data->first = 0;
    index_fork = 0;
    pid_t pid[data->last];
    

    while (curr != NULL) 
    {   
        if ((curr->type == E_WORD && curr->next != NULL) && (curr->next->Token_str[0] == '>') && (curr->next->next->type == E_FILE))   
        {
            pid[index_fork] = -1;        
            pid[index_fork] = fork_process_redi(data, curr, envp, list_token);
            index_fork++;
        }
        if (((curr->type == E_WORD || curr->next->type ==  E_FILE ) && curr->next != NULL && curr->next->Token_str[0] == '|') && (curr->type == E_WORD && curr->next == NULL))
        {        
            pid[index_fork] = -1;        
            create_pipe(data->pipe_fd, index_fork, data->last);
            pid[index_fork] = fork_process_pipe(index_fork, input_fd, data, curr, envp, list_token);
            close_pipes_in_parent(index_fork, data, &input_fd);
            index_fork++;

        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    wait_for_children(data->last, pid);
}
```

When i ruen crestain test like `ls | wc > a` my PID seems to remain indefinitely wating, whereas when i execute
hen `ls | cat fichier.txt > a`, it works correctly

-> [image test0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fC1Z.png) <-

-> [image test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T1WD.png) <-

-> [lldb witch will test "ls | wc > test.txt"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR906.png)<-

Comment: Well, what's the difference between your two examples?  `wc` reads from stdin, while `cat fichier.txt` does not.  So probably `wc` is trying to read from stdin, and it's waiting (it never gets EOF).  Try to debug that.

Comment: The remark "*it doesn't redirect the output of `'ls | wc'` to this file*" suggests a possible misconception that may be relevant.  Although it's true that `ls | wc > a` should redirect the output of the pipeline to file `a`, that's because the output of the pipeline is the output of the last command in it.  You should achieve the desired effect by redirecting specifically the output of the `wc` command.  That needs to be your conception of the problem, else you risk solving the *wrong* problem.

Comment: It might be worth your while to first solve a model problem with a hardcoded combination of pipeline and [other] redirection(s).  Make that as short and simple as possible, so that you are not distracted by all the abstraction and framing.

Comment: Side note: In this context, "Bash" is the name of a *specific* shell.  It is not a generic term.  It is inappropriate for your shell to identify itself as "Bash".

Comment: What you've provided is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  The data types (notably `t_data` but also `t_Token` and others) are missing.  There's no `main()` function.  The content of the data structures for the two command lines is not shown.  Note that `ls | cat fichier.txt > a` means that `cat` does not read its standard input.  By contrast, `ls | wc > a` means that `wc` does.

Comment: When printing diagnostic messages, make sure the message ends with a newline.  The `printf("111111111111111111");` output may not appear until another message outputs a newline.  If the standard output is going to a file, it may not appear until the buffer is full.  Some systems may produce the output as if the standard output was unbuffered, but it is unwise to rely on that.  Besides, debugging messages should usually be more helpful than a string of ones.

Comment: it works I will test thank you for your involvement

Comment: actually my output from my command does not work but I cannot find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fork_process_redi you are setting the output file descriptor but not the input, like you are doing in fork_process_pipe. The last command in pipeline with redirection will be reading from STDIN until EoF readed instead from the pipe of the last command. "cat file" will not read from stdin and it runs ok.

Not related, but the free sentences after execve will never be executed. The memory is freed when the forked process exits so it's not an issue.

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve my problem by returning the input_fd in my redirection function , should I send my correction now?

Comment: I do not know too much about stack overflow protocol but I think that if you edit your question and add the new code, it will be clearer and more usable for future readers with similar problems.